# How shared library dependencies are resolved?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have built two shared libraries - libvpx.so and libmyapp.so. Library libmyapp.so depends on libvpx.so.

My .apk file contains both the libraries under the standard `lib/armeabi` directory.

In my java file, I have:

```
class MyVPX {
   static {
     System.LoadLibrary("myapp");
   }
   ...
}
```

When the app is run, I get an unsatisfied-link-error that libvpx.so was not found while loading libmyapp.so.

If I explicitly load libvpx.so, everything works as expected:

```
class MyVPX {
   static {
     System.LoadLibrary("vpx");
     System.LoadLibrary("myapp");
   }
   ...
}
```

I am wondering if anyone knows what causes this?

Comment: Is libmyapp linked against libvpx (e.g., with `-lvpx`)?

Comment: Linkage is specified but not with "-lvpx." Under NDK, it has a different mechanism for app-specific shared libaries. Plus, if linkage was not specified, I wouldn't have received unsatisfied-link-error :-). Regards.

Comment: Who knows, you could be using dlopen *and* compile time linking. :) In general, the apk native library path is added to the `java.library.path` property, so this dependency should be getting resolved.. Can you post the Application.mk, Android.mk, any other relevant Makefiles and the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. Android loader only looks for dependencies in `/system/lib` folder, and there is no way to let it automatically load the libraries in you app native library dir. There is an inherent security reason for that, see ["Bionic linker's LD_LIBRARY_PATH limitation"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/m6OddFQINxs/fuwuQHyuRNMJ) and other threads in the [android-ndk forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-ndk).

On the other hand, from Java you can load libraries from other app's library dirs, or even from the sdcard.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I suspected that LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not being extended. Now it is confirmed. Regards.